# Cannot access Jenkins installed in a container

Tags: docker, jenkins

I want to setup a dev environment on a Ubuntu container.

I have run the container as follow:

```
docker run -tid \
  --name auto-server \
  --rm \
  --volume data:/home/ubuntu \
  --publish 8080:8080 \
  --cap-add=NET_ADMIN \
  --cap-add=NET_RAW \
  ubuntu:latest
```

Within, I have installed Jenkins and its dependencies.

The 8080 port seems to be ok on the container:

[image]

The Jenkins daemon also, here is the output I have requesting it in my container, here is what i get when I request **http://localhost:8080**:

[image]

My problem is how to access Jenkins web UI from my browser.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are going through the trouble of setting it up manually. You could just use the official docker image (https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker).

Comment: Yes, I want my development environment to run on a Ubuntu container as my server will be also on Ubuntu. I don't know if I can deploy all my dependencies on a Jenkins container.

Comment: It looks like you're running a bare `ubuntu` container.  That won't have any of the software you need installed.  As @smelm says using a prebuilt Jenkins container would be better; if you can't use that, can you provide a [mcve] explaining what you installed and configured?  (Ideally this would be in the form of a reproducible `Dockerfile`.)

Comment: True, but its easier to install my dependencies on a bare metal Ubuntu container rather than making sure the Jenkins container is running on a Debian os. Anyway it should not be that difficult to setup Jenkins on a random container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--network` [`bridge`](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/) already is the default, unless specified otherwise.

Just add `EXPOSE 8080` to the `Dockerfile` (or script) and it should work.

Comment: I don't think this will actually have any effect; "expose" means very little in modern Docker.